# Setting Background Image with BrowserAction

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, background, google-chrome-extension, browser-action

i am learning how to write chrome extensions, i found one example where, using a browseaction it´s posible to change the backgroundcolor of the webpage, i am trying to do something really similar, changing the backgroundimage, but for some reason...it is not working, the js function is:

```
function click(e) {
  chrome.tabs.executeScript(null,
      {code:"document.body.style.background=url('ffrontier.jpg')"});
  window.close();
}
```

I am pretty sure it is something about my sintax but i cant figure it out, can anybody help me? THANKS A LOT

Answer (score 2):

First of all you need to specify the resource in manifest.json file (see [Web Accessible Resources](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest.html#web_accessible_resources)) like this:

```
"web_accessible_resources": ["ffrontier.jpg"]
```

Secondly, you should specify complete image url like this:

```
function click(e) {
  chrome.tabs.executeScript(null,
      {code:"var imgURL = chrome.extension.getURL('ffrontier.jpg'); document.body.style.backgroundImage='url(' + imgURL + ')'"});
  window.close();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE: only external urls like url(http://www.stackoverflow.com) work, NOT local files. Sorry.
I simply removed the quote marks in `url()` and it's working for me!

```
function click(e) {
  chrome.tabs.executeScript(null,
      {code:"document.body.style.backgroundImage = 'url(ffrontier.jpg)'"});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the `background-image` property, not the `background` property (which refers to the background color of the page).

```
function click(e) {
  chrome.tabs.executeScript(null,
      {code:"document.body.style[background-image]=\"url('ffrontier.jpg')\""});
  window.close();
}
```

Something to note: `document.body.style.background-image` will throw an error because you can't use the `-` symbol in variable names. You have to use object syntax instead:

```
document.body.style[background-image]
```

Comment: Make sure the image url is valid as well.

Comment: Already checked, thats the name of the image.....it is not something about the "" ?

Comment: @xiidarkevil: I think that might be it. Give me a sec... --*edit*-- Okay, I've updated the answer, I think we were missing a set of quotes. Try it again?

Comment: Probably it should be `document.body.style.backgroundImage`